# Testing clock skew of multiple servers

Tags: linux

Is there a Linux utility to test the current clock skew of a group of servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using MRTG combined with NTP to monitor the clocks.

Here is the articles that I used when setting it all up.  Though I used a python script and library instead of Perl for the NTP.

- http://www.satsignal.eu/ntp/NTPandMRTG.html
- http://www.infradapt.com/csma_apps/ntpstat.shtml

Comment: Later I'll post my configs and scripts.

Comment: On a similar vein, Munin (by default) checks ntp peers/skew/jitter/etc by default as well, and will give you nice pretty graphs. :)

Comment: There is also collectd (http://collectd.org/) - there are a number of good monitoring tools that have NTP monitoring modules.